# DryIOC and MediatR: Injection using InResolutionScopeOf for both IAsyncNotificationHandler and IAsyncRequestHandler

Tags: dryioc, mediatr

This question is a follow up to my previous question, [DryIOC Decorator and InResolutionScopeOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244178/dryioc-decorator-and-inresolutionscopeof/40300649?noredirect=1#comment68431818_40300649)

What I'm trying to do is create EF DbContext instances in the resolution scope of both IAsyncRequestHandler and IAsyncNotificationHandler, meaning the context injected in a request can't be the same as one injected in a notification (published from a request). Since the notifications are published from inside the request handlers, this nesting is creating some troubles with my desired setup.

It is worth noting that each DbContext injected in a given IAsyncRequestHandler or IAsyncNotificationHandler instance needs to be the same across their own decorators.

I've created a dotnetfiddle with my attempt at setting this up https://dotnetfiddle.net/KiFCHY. (I've ommitted decorators in this example)

It contains a RequestHandler which prints a message when it is called, and it then publishes a notification, which prints another message. However, as you can see, the notification isn't called because MediatR cannot get the IAsyncNotificationHandler instance (because it can't resolve the DbContext).

Is this setup possible?

Thanks

Comment: Looking at problem, but for now only rough guesses. Will add an answer as soon as I get a clue.

Comment: @dadhi, i believe the problem lies in the MultiInstanceFactory registration, which resolves using ResolveMany, instead of Resolve. It seems that with ResolveMany, the dependencies aren't resolved properly in this case. I've edited the fiddle and added a commented line https://dotnetfiddle.net/KiFCHY

Comment: A good finding! Will dig from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the root cause: `ResolveMany<object>(serviceType)`  which is used in MediatR setup.

An `object` identifies that you need to pass run-time required `serviceType`. But DryIoc has an issue of using service type `object` instead of required type to find the matching resolution scope. And an `object` is definitely not assignable to `IAsyncNotificationHandler<T>`.

Here is the modified [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BJnmcr)

Stay tuned for the fix. I will update my answer with the fix version.

#### Updated with fix version

The fix is released with [DryIoc 2.9.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DryIoc.dll). Here is [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iZItEY) which uses it. Thanks for asking and surfacing 2 issues - real use cases matter the most.

Comment: Alright @dadhi, once again, thanks a lot for the help and keep up the good work.